# Pl-sql Procedure to print table details

Tags: plsql, cursor, procedure

SQL. I have created 1 procedure but I am not getting the desired output. My procedure is below:

```
--/
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Update_TB_INTERACTLOG
IS
BEGIN
    FOR records in (select TNAME from tab where TNAME like 'TB_INTERACTLOG%' and TABTYPE = 'TABLE')
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(records.TNAME||' modified');
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

There are 7 records I am getting from select query.

This I am getting in Log Output.

**13:10:02  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.031 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.031/0.000 sec [0 successful, 1 warnings, 0 errors]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you have created the procedure but not executed it. To execute it, run the following code:

```
exec Update_TB_INTERACTLOG;
```

Furthermore, you will need to turn on DBMS output in the tool you're using to run it (unless it's SQL*plus).

And please not that the procedure wasn't properly compiled (*1 warnings*). The procedure should probably end with:

```
END Update_TB_INTERACTLOG;
```

instead of:

```
END;
```